# Pure functional programming to the GPU

Tags: functional-programming, cuda, opencl, gpu

I've been wanting to play around with functional code, and thought what fun it would be to do some interactive real-time ray-tracing of some randomly composed functions. Does anyone know of any compiler or converter that can take code from a functional language (or any language, with high order functions) and convert it into something that can be used in CUDA or OpenCL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several embedded languages in Haskell that target CUDA and/or OpenCL.

The most high level is [accelerate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/accelerate), a subset of Haskell for array processing, embedded in Haskell. It works with CUDA.

Conal Elliott has a [shader language](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shady-gen) embedded in Haskell, for graphics programming

Answer (score 2):

There are some attempts, such as [Obsidian](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Ejoels/writing/dccpaper_obsidian.pdf) (Haskell) and SaC (Single Assignment C).

More about this and some other attempts are described in this paper:
[Functional Programming for High-Performance Computing on Heterogeneous Architectures](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/347158897_A_Platform_Programming_Paradigm_for_Heterogeneous_Systems_Integration)

Comment: Apparently they took the full article offline. I changed the link to the description page with abstract.